How to fit a Bayesian model to a mixture of Beta and One-Zero inflated data?
I have very noisy data, which I believe is created through interactions of multiple physical processes. In the mapping $Y = f(X),$ $Y$ is a ratio $[0, 1]$ and $X \ge 0.$ While $Y$ is a function of $X,$ it can also take $0$ (more likely at lower $X$ values) or $1$ (more likely at higher $X$ values). $Y$ is a mixture of Beta and Zero-One inflated processes at each $X$ interval.
The conditional distribution of $Y$, (i.e., $Y|X$ ) for select intervals of $X$ show a similar pattern to the marginal distribution of the data (shown below). However, the spread in $Y|X$ is more pronounced at lower values of $X$ and slowly vanishes as $X$ increases.
How can I model such a process using Bayesian methods? I'm new to Bayesian Statistics and would appreciate any help. I'm able to fit zero-one inflated Beta model, but it is not able to capture the high spread of $Y$ at lower $X$​ values.
While there are other features of the data that could reduce model error, especially at higher $X$, they are typically unobservable in most applications. Consequently, I'm aiming for a function that can offer the best possible mapping for facilitating real-world application.
Dummy data mimicking the real data:
# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Generate x values
x <- seq(0, 20, length.out = 1000)

# Create a non-linear function for y
y <-  0.15 + 0.005 * x^1.05 + 1 / (2.5 + 2532 * exp(-1.611 * x))

# Add some random noise
noise_factor <- 0.03
# Making the model with beta noise (here created using normal distribution)
noisy_y <- rnorm(length(x), mean = 0, sd = noise_factor * sqrt(x))

y <- y + noisy_y

# Add zero and one noise to the data
noisy_indices <- sample(1:length(x), round(0.2 * length(x)))
for (i in noisy_indices) {
  if (runif(1) < 1 / (1 + exp(x[i]))) {
    y[i] <- 1
  } else {
    y[i] <- 0
  }
}

# Add exponential distribution
noisy_indices <- sample(1:length(x), round(0.5 * length(x)))
for (i in noisy_indices) {
  if (runif(1) < 100 / (1 + exp(x[i]))) {
    y[i] <- rexp(1, rate =4)
  } else {
    y[i] <- y[i]
  }
}

# Create the dataframe
data <- data.frame(x = x, y = y) |>
        filter(y<=1 & y>=0)

ggplot(data, 
        aes(x, y)) +
        geom_point()  +
        xlim(0, 20) + 
        ylim(0, 1)

ggplot(data = data, 
aes(x=y))+
geom_histogram()

I'm trying for formulate a function that maps X to Y

Distribution of Y in the entire dataset. In the original dataset, the transition from Zero (@Y=0) to the Exponential portion (Y ~ 0-0.25) is very smooth.

My attempt (on the original data) using a Zero-One Inflated Beta in brms yields this posterior predictive:


Are there any other important predictors here?

@Glen_b Yes, there are other predictors. Specifically, features of entities that were exposed to X.

This will affect both the appearance of the conditional mean, the conditional variance and the shape of the conditional distribution; the marginal bivariate plot will not be particularly informative about the conditional relationship in general. Either added-variable plots or residual plots may be more use

Here is the best I could do

I fit a zero-one inflated beta regression and allows the mean and the dispersion to be a smooth.  The brms syntax is

fit <- brm(
  bf(y ~ s(x),
     phi ~ s(x)),
  data=data, 
  family = zero_one_inflated_beta(),
  backend = 'cmdstanr',
  cores=4,
  adapt_delta = 0.99
)


pp_check(fit, ndraws=100)
```


This began as a comment but grew a bit long. I guess it's at least the start of a kind of answer.
Y can't have an actual exponential component; it's bounded at 1. You must mean something else there (e.g. maybe a winsorized exponential?)
It's also not clear to me how you assert that an exponential (or something akin to it) is present; I don't see it in the conditional distribution; all I see is a larger spread at low values. This might indicate any number of things and may be modelled in a number of ways.
It's very important to note that for a model of Y in terms of x, it's the conditional distribution of Y - not the marginal distribution - that you worry about a model for. Looking at the histogram of the marginal distribution may lead you into trying to model features of the distribution that are not relevant, but caused by the arrangement of x's.
It looks like a pretty standard 0/1-inflated beta regression model would be at least fairly adequate, but there's some aspects that make even that choice imperfect - the usual logistic link is not quite right and the dispersion (inverse of the precision parameter) doesn't look like would be constant. The first problem is solvable within the framework, the second may more of an issue but it's hard to tell without looking at something akin to suitably standardized residuals (you need to remove the effect of the variance function and the impact that slope has on the visual impression of spread).
I note you've used the mixed model tag but it seems like you're talking about a mixture distribution rather than a model with some random-effect component (a GLMM-like model). It would be good to make it clear if it's not intended to be a mixed model.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model - in particular, the "not to be confused with mixture model" thing right under the title.
Edit: The existence of other relevant covariates will affect both the appearance of the conditional mean, the conditional variance and the shape of the conditional distribution; the marginal bivariate plot will not be particularly informative about the conditional relationship in general; indeed much or all that appearance of mixing and heteroskedasticity may be due to those ignored covariates $-$ in the same way that a univariate marginal histogram was misleading in relation to the conditional distribution you seek a model for that was described earlier.
Either added-variable plots or residual plots (in each case with important covariates included) may be more use than a marginal plot.

Thank you for taking the time and sharing your expertise. I have updated the question in response to your comment.
I have removed the reference to the exponential distribution. At any select interval, the conditional distribution Y|X looked like a mix of two beta distributions (one skewed to the right and the other closer to a normal distribution) and the Zero-One Inflated model.

The problem's physics can explain the large spread at lower X. At lower X, multiple failure modes interact to create the response Y, but such interactions are limited at higher X. However, which failure modes interact at what stage are hidden (not observed in the available data).
I'm also wrong about the Mixed-Model.

Useful additional information. Consider adding this sort of information to the question as it might impact answers.

TLDR: check that the method works on toy-data; check that the predicted conditional distributions at any $x$ are a good fit to the data.
You already have several great technical answers. I want to try to take a step back to define:

a high-level overview that I think is acceptable for your model as I understand it (and it's very possible that I have missed key details).
how I would define success in fitting such a model.
How I would try to fit a Bayesian model to this particular situation.

Problem analysis
As far as I can see, in your problem, you have the following features:

A regression problem over a bounded range, with data everywhere.

it's a tricky problem: we want to share information between adjacent values of $x$ but not create too much bias.


Lots of data (I think?)

that balances out a lot of trickiness of the regression problem


Funky mixtures, but over a restricted range

you highlight four components:

$Y=0$
$Y=1$
small values $Y\approx 0.05$ (exponential-like, but of course with restricted range; beta with appropriate parameters)
"big" values $Y\approx 0.6$; beta?


this is a major source of trouble




Success conditions
Any method we propose is going to be a complex beast. My criteria for success would be the following

Ignoring the regression, my model works:

On data generated from a 4 component mixture, we correctly recover the parameters of the mixture, over a wide range of parameters.
ie, if I run an experiment, with data that is as nice as can be, my method works fine.


Adding the regression, my model works:

on data generated from a regression model smoothly modifying the parameters of a 4 component mixture, we correctly recover the parameters of the mixture
again, if I run an experiment, with data that is as nice as can be, my method works fine.


On the actual data, I correctly predict the conditional distribution of data

at every $x$, we predict a distribution for $y$. Let's check that the predicted conditional distribution and the empirical conditional distribution match at every point.
I'm not quite sure how to do this in practice. My first idea is a (conditional) QQ-plot on all the data, allowing a slight tolerance for $y$.
would a QQ-plot have issues with discrete values? I'm worried about this.
another idea is a proper scoring rule applied to the conditional distribution on validation data



Bayesian model
Here is a Bayesian model that has to be manually fit.

for the mixture, let's split into three components temporarily:

The two discrete components
The continuous component, which will be a mixture of two beta.


the advantage here is that the probability of each component can be fit wihtout considering the precise value of $Y$, only whether it is $0, 1$ or in-between.
we can fit this with any gaussian process


now, we only need to model the continuous component

fitting a mixture of two beta should not be horrible (due to the beta being an exponential family), but we have the issue that the parameters should evolve with x
but a simple solution to this is to organize the x in blocks and assume that the parameters are constant on each block
for inference, MCMC inside of each block, to compute the posterior distribution of the $y$ ??
expectation-maximization could be available, but mcmc feels better



All of this can also be fitted in a non-bayesian manner instead. That's where the sanity checks validating that the method works on toy-data would be important.
